# Why Mongoose is responding null field when it exists in DB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I don't know if this a mongoose bug or I'm doing something wrong, my problem is:

I have some documents in the mongoDB these have an attribute called address and inside it have an country which is an object id but when I make a query using mongoose this country id comes as "null":

**Mongoose Schema**

```
{
password: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: true,
    index: true
},
email: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: true,
    index: {
        unique: true
    }
},
address: {
    address: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    },
    city: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    },
    zipCode: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    },
    country: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Country',
        default: '54e635cb4ef1d41d99b837e8',
        required: true
    }
}
```

}

**MongoDB document:**

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("54b7ff802d244c9f224c78f4"),
   "password" : "12345",
   "email" : "email@email.com",
   // ...
   "address" : {
       "country" : ObjectId("54e635cb4ef1d41d99b837e8"),
       "zipCode" : "",
       "city" : "",
       "address" : ""
   }
}
```

**Mongoose query**

```
Model.findOne({
   email: 'email@email.com',
   password: '12345'
}, function(err, model) { /* ... */ });
```

**Mongoose response**

```
{
"_id": "54b7ff802d244c9f224c78f4",
"email": "email@email.com",
"password" : "12345",
// ...
"address": {
    "country": null,
    "zipCode": "",
    "city": "",
    "address": ""
}
```

}

I really don't know why country is coming as null.
My Mongo version is 2.6.6 and mongoose version is 3.8.21.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you edit your question to add your schema definition?

Comment: Thanks JohnnyHK, I just add it

Comment: Hmm...it worked fine when I tried it with that schema and sample doc.

Answer (score 1):

This can be fixed using [populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

```
Model.findOne({
   email: 'email@email.com',
   password: '12345'
}).populate('address country').exec(function (error, user) {
  // ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks but... Actually the idea is populate the country, but mongoose can't make it because the value is coming as null.

Comment: does your complete query involve `.select('some fields of the user but no_address')` ?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it, I'll describe how did I fix it:

1. Update mongoose to 3.8.23 (I don't think it made any difference).
2. When I was running the init script, the script imports a csv doc with countries data, so the country _id changes on each mongoimport; so I made a mongodump and now in init script I restore the collection instead importing it.

I think this last point made the difference because of the _id; in the schema I'm setting an default ObjectId that does not exists in the collection, thats why i decided to make an restore, to hold all _id's.